# Relationship between limit of sequence and essential supremum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, uniform-convergence

I've noticed many posts regarding conditions for which you can interchange limits and essential supremum so please forgive me if this is somewhat of a duplicate. I believe my problem may be phrased differently to many of these posts. Here is my question:

- Suppose that $\mathrm{ess \ sup}_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$, can we deduce from this that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ for each $x\in X$ or vice versa? Or would this require uniform convergence of the sequence $(f_n)$ in order to interchange limits?

Comment: What do you mean by $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert \to 0$?

Comment: @AndrewZhang Sorry. Edits gave been made.

Comment: Take $f_n(x) = 0$ and$f(x) = [x=0]$. Then the essential supremum is zero for all $n$, but clearly $f(0)-f_n(0) =1$ for all $n$. If that is what you meant by $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT:] The comment indicated that the question was not answered. Suppose for each $x\in X$ we know that $\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. What can be said about $\mathrm{ess\,sup}\vert f-f_n\vert$? The following example gives an answer.

Take $X = (0,1)$, $f_n(x) = cx^n$ and $f(x) = 0$. Then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for each fixed $x$ and $n\to\infty$ but $\mathrm{ess\,sup}\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert = \vert c\vert$ for each $n$.

Can anything be  said to the converse? That is, if $\mathrm{ess\,sup}\vert f-f_n\vert \to 0$ can we say anything about the behavior of $\vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert$ for each $x\in X$.

The answer is that if $D = \{x\in X: \liminf_{n}\vert f_n(x) - f(x)\vert > 0\}$ (the set of points which do not converge) then $\mu(D) = 0$.

Comment: I'm not too sure if I follow. What happens if we fix any value of $x\in X$ and we know that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Can we say that $\mathrm{ess \ sup}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ also tends to zero?

Comment: Oh that is a fair question, one which I did not answer. The answer to that question is no even if a finiteness assumption is given. Take$X = (0,1)$, $f_n(x) = x^n$ and $f(x) = 0$. Then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for each fixed $x$ and $n\to\infty$ but $\mathrm{ess\,sup}\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert = 1$ for each $n$

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice counter-example. In your answer above is this illustrating that if $\mu(X)<\infty$ then $\mathrm{ess \ sup}_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ means that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ for each $x\in X$? Here I am only interested in the standard euclidean norm.

Comment: If each $f_n$ and $f$ is required to be continuous, then yes, even if no finiteness assumption is assumed. If no continuity is required then the comment I left in your question provides an example where this fails.

The proofs I provided in my post are for $L^p$ norms, which I don't think are relevant to your question, but I am not sure of the procedure for this (should I delete my post, or delete the irrelevant parts??)

Comment: I have chosen to edit the post to more directly answer the questions.